# "combined with the fact that" and "this means"

Tags: participle-phrases

If "combined with the fact that" is used in the following, could "this means" be omitted? Does it make sense to omit it?

> Blue light is harmful to your health. Yet, we cannot avoid all electronic devices. **Combined with the fact that** the average person’s intake of vegetables is generally not enough, **this means** staying healthy in today’s electronic world can be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not omit *this means* from your sentence.

*This* is referring to the two previous sentences. The *combined with...* clause is not modifying the entire sentence -- it is actually just modifying *this*.

If you remove *this means* from the sentence, you change the meaning of the sentence to:

> Staying healthy in today’s electronic world, combined with the fact that the average person’s intake of vegetables is generally not enough, can be difficult.

This doesn't really make sense -- at least, it is not the meaning intended.

If the entire *combined with* clause weren't there, you could either keep or remove *this means*.